# ASP.NET REST retrieve posta data

Tags: rest, post

I'm using a jQuery Web App, and I need to send photo's data from a mobile device, to be stored in a SQL Server DB. Data is too long to be transmitted in a parameter, so I've to use POST Data. How can I get these data? In interface? In implementation function? TIA

```
IUpdateDati.vb

<OperationContract()> <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="insertfoto/?uid={userid}&pwd={password}&dioc={dioc}&coda={coda}&foto={foto}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Function InsertFoto(userid As String, password As String, dioc As String, coda As String, foto As String) As String

UpdateDati.vb

Public Function InsertFoto(userid As String, password As String, dioc As String, coda As String, foto As String) As String Implements IUpdateDati.InsertFoto
Dim img As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(foto)
Dim sqnCs = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CamminoSqlDB").ConnectionString
Dim sqc As New SqlConnection(sqnCs)
Dim cmdUpFoto As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Anagrafica SET Foto = @Foto WHERE CodDiocesi = " + CStr(dioc) + " AND CodAnagrafica = " + CStr(coda), sqc)
Dim parFoto As New SqlParameter("@Foto", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image)
parFoto.Value = img
cmdUpFoto.Parameters.Add(parFoto)
sqc.Open()
Dim rkUpd = cmdUpFoto.ExecuteNonQuery()
sqc.Close()
Return "Foto aggiornata correttamente"
End Function

Web.config

<service name="RestSvc4Gescom.UpdateDati" behaviorConfiguration="httpBehaviour">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestSvc4Gescom.IUpdateDati" behaviorConfiguration="httpEndpointBehavour">
<identity>
<dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="http://localhost/RestSvc4Gescom/" />
</baseAddresses>
</host>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer by myself. Since I believe i can help someonem I'm posting it. Basically, I'm omitting the POST DATA parameter from UriTemplate, and declare it in Function parameters as Stream.

Interface IUpdateDati.vb
     
    Function InsertFoto(userid As String, password As String, dioc As String, coda As String, foto As Stream) As String

Implementing Function UpdateDati.vb

```
Public Function InsertFoto(userid As String, password As String, dioc As String, coda As String, foto As Stream) As String Implements IUpdateDati.InsertFoto
    Dim leggi As String = New StreamReader(foto).ReadToEnd
    Dim img As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(leggi)
    Dim sqnCs = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CamminoSqlDB").ConnectionString
    Dim sqc As New SqlConnection(sqnCs)
    Dim cmdUpFoto As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Anagrafica SET Foto = @Foto WHERE CodDiocesi = " + CStr(dioc) + " AND CodAnagrafica = " + CStr(coda), sqc)
    Dim parFoto As New SqlParameter("@Foto", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image)
    parFoto.Value = img
    cmdUpFoto.Parameters.Add(parFoto)
    sqc.Open()
    Dim rkUpd = cmdUpFoto.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqc.Close()
    Return "Foto aggiornata correttamente"
End Function
```